# Python: Get multiple random lines for a given category

Tags: python, random, line, categories

I am a Python beginner who is trying to get multiple random lines for a given category. The original file has three columns, but what I am interested is just one of those categories. The file(csv) looks like this:

```
   No,Size,Name
   10,1346,Cat
   24,423,Dog
   289,590,Cat
   12,302,Dog
   351,33,Cat
   51,812,Dog
   91,778,Cat
   1193,465,Cat
   44,178,Dog
```

None of the lines are identical and I want to get random 3 lines for each 'Name'. This is what I have so far:

```
import random

with open('C:\Users\Owl\file.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[1:] #Skip heading

for line in lines:
    try:
        name = line[2]
    except:
        continue

for name in lines:
    for lines in random.sample(lines,3):
        print lines

f.close()
```

But I get something like this:

```
   12,302,Dog
   1193,465,Cat
   10,1346,Cat
   2
   3
   D
```

instead of something like this:

```
   1193,465,Cat
   10,1346,Cat
   91,778,Cat
   51,812,Dog
   44,178,Dog
   12,302,Dog
```

In the output I get now, I am not getting lines by 'Name' and somehow just letters/numbers after that. Then, I get "ValueError: sample larger than population" and terminates (actual file is much larger than the example here).

Also, if possible, is there an easy way to sort by "Name" in the output?

I have been struggling with this for hours looking it up on the Internet but have not been able to solve... Could anybody please help me? Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this much more easily by using [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html). We first make a `csv.DictReader` to give us easy access to the values, we then sort and group the list by the `"Name"` column, and then select the values.

```
import itertools
import csv
import operator
import random

with open("test.csv") as file:
    data = csv.DictReader(file)
    key = operator.itemgetter("Name")
    for name, items in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=key), key):
        print(name+":", random.sample(list(items), 3))
```

Which gives us:

```
Cat: [{'Size': '33', 'Name': 'Cat', 'No': '351'}, {'Size': '590', 'Name': 'Cat', 'No': '289'}, {'Size': '465', 'Name': 'Cat', 'No': '1193'}]
Dog: [{'Size': '178', 'Name': 'Dog', 'No': '44'}, {'Size': '812', 'Name': 'Dog', 'No': '51'}, {'Size': '302', 'Name': 'Dog', 'No': '12'}]
```

If you wish to make the dictionaries lists, it's easy to do with a simple [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY&list=UUAuqj5Bs5mTTl1mIVDmuAlw&index=1&feature=plcp):

```
[[item["No"], item["Size"], item["Name"]] for item in items]
```

Comment: Do you add individual name (e.g. "Cat") in "Name" here? I tried doing so but I get KeyError: 'Cat'

Comment: No. It's the name of the column to select. I suggest you read through and try to understand what the code is doing before you use it.

Comment: Thank you and sorry. I am still having a lot of troubles understanding the structure etc. My sincere apologies. Would making dictionaries lists not print the keys for each items?

Comment: No need to apologise, it was just a suggestion. As to using lists, yes, you could use them like any other lists.

Comment: Thank you. As you have shown me, I am now being able to extract each line as dictionary in my original file but not being able to eliminate the keys... :( As in the example above, I just want lines with no keys or apostrophes. I will keep on trying to fix my codes!

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting a lot of variables:

- The `name` in your first `for line in lines` is never used.
- You loop on `for name in lines`, then don't use `name` but start a second loop `for lines in random.sample(lines, 3)`: you're just confusing Python: what is `lines` now ? A random element of `lines`.. and then, you go back looping on this new element. You could try something like:

  ```
  for name in lines:
      for row in random.sample(lines, 3):
          ...
  ```

That will help a bit, but not a lot: you're still looping on the original file.

I suggest you start building a dictionary storing a list of lines for each `name`

```
names = defaultdict(list)
for line in lines:
    fields = line.split()
    names[fields[2]].append(line)
```

Then, for each `name` of `names`, take a random sample as `random.sample(names[name], 3)`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what I did wrong. I started learning Python without somebody teaching me so I still do a lot of stupid mistakes and have a lot of troubles understanding the structures and grammars. I will try your method now.